# How to programmatically disable edge swipe gesture of the windows 10 tablet screen?

Tags: c#, winforms, touchscreen

Tried both programmatically and manually modify the registry for both DisableCharmsHint and DisableTLcorner to 1 under EdgeUI of immersiveShell (to disable touch screen swipe edges), after restart nothing happens.

Just want to disable the swipe from edges to prevent user from accessing other application but just my application as currently opened, and will later enable the swipe edges again once my application is closed (back to normal).

the application running is a windows form (not WPF) c# app coming from the desktop and run in the windows 10 tablet.

is there any other way to prevent user from swiping the edges and from opening the windows respective to each edge from edge swipe

Comment: They're not there for you (your program), they're there for the user.

Comment: yes,  it is for the user but at least if my app is open, prevent user from swiping to select other app, or go to settings etc, like a lock, similar to how android games work where swiping the gestures did not open the notification screen

Comment: I agree with Damien that you need to be careful with hiding regular user interface components. But there are some legitimate usecases for disabling the swipe, e.g. full screen games and kiosk mode applications.

Answer (score 9):

I know this thread is old, but couldn't find concise and clear solution anywhere. Had the same issue with our kiosk application (WIN7 PC's automatically updated to WIN 10). Tried everything from registry/group policy changes, to dirty windows shell hacks - nothing worked. So thanks to link Koen_R [provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889683/how-do-i-turn-off-windows-8-1-gestures-and-setting-charm-bar-on-my-touch-screen) managed to get it working (code below is Ron Schuler's answer converted from VB to c#).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Your_Namespace
{


    public static class EdgeGestureUtil
    {

        private static Guid DISABLE_TOUCH_SCREEN = new Guid("32CE38B2-2C9A-41B1-9BC5-B3784394AA44");
        private static Guid IID_PROPERTY_STORE = new Guid("886d8eeb-8cf2-4446-8d02-cdba1dbdcf99");

        private static short VT_BOOL = 11;
        #region "Structures"

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
        public struct PropertyKey
        {
            public PropertyKey(Guid guid, UInt32 pid)
            {
                fmtid = guid;
                this.pid = pid;
            }

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
            public Guid fmtid;
            public uint pid;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        public struct PropVariant
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public short vt;
            [FieldOffset(2)]
            private short wReserved1;
            [FieldOffset(4)]
            private short wReserved2;
            [FieldOffset(6)]
            private short wReserved3;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            private sbyte cVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            private byte bVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            private short iVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            public ushort uiVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            private int lVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            private uint ulVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            private int intVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            private uint uintVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            private long hVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            private long uhVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            private float fltVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            private double dblVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            public bool boolVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            private int scode;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            private DateTime date;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            private System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME filetime;

            [FieldOffset(8)]
            private Blob blobVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            private IntPtr pwszVal;


            /// <summary>
            /// Helper method to gets blob data
            /// </summary>
            private byte[] GetBlob()
            {
                byte[] Result = new byte[blobVal.Length];
                Marshal.Copy(blobVal.Data, Result, 0, Result.Length);
                return Result;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Property value
            /// </summary>
            public object Value
            {
                get
                {
                    VarEnum ve = (VarEnum)vt;
                    switch (ve)
                    {
                        case VarEnum.VT_I1:
                            return bVal;
                        case VarEnum.VT_I2:
                            return iVal;
                        case VarEnum.VT_I4:
                            return lVal;
                        case VarEnum.VT_I8:
                            return hVal;
                        case VarEnum.VT_INT:
                            return iVal;
                        case VarEnum.VT_UI4:
                            return ulVal;
                        case VarEnum.VT_LPWSTR:
                            return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pwszVal);
                        case VarEnum.VT_BLOB:
                            return GetBlob();
                    }
                    throw new NotImplementedException("PropVariant " + ve.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        internal struct Blob
        {
            public int Length;

            public IntPtr Data;
            //Code Should Compile at warning level4 without any warnings, 
            //However this struct will give us Warning CS0649: Field [Fieldname] 
            //is never assigned to, and will always have its default value
            //You can disable CS0649 in the project options but that will disable
            //the warning for the whole project, it's a nice warning and we do want 
            //it in other places so we make a nice dummy function to keep the compiler
            //happy.
            private void FixCS0649()
            {
                Length = 0;
                Data = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region "Interfaces"

        [ComImport(), Guid("886D8EEB-8CF2-4446-8D02-CDBA1DBDCF99"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        public interface IPropertyStore
        {
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
            void GetCount([Out(),In()] ref uint cProps);
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
            void GetAt([In()] uint iProp, ref PropertyKey pkey);
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
            void GetValue([In()] ref PropertyKey key, ref PropVariant pv);
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
            void SetValue([In()] ref PropertyKey key, [In()] ref PropVariant pv);
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
            void Commit();
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
            void Release();
        }

        #endregion

        #region "Methods"

        [DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow(IntPtr handle, ref Guid riid, ref IPropertyStore propertyStore);

        public static void DisableEdgeGestures(IntPtr hwnd, bool enable)
        {
            IPropertyStore pPropStore = null;
            int hr = 0;
            hr = SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow(hwnd, ref IID_PROPERTY_STORE, ref pPropStore);
            if (hr == 0)
            {
                PropertyKey propKey = new PropertyKey();
                propKey.fmtid = DISABLE_TOUCH_SCREEN;
                propKey.pid = 2;
                PropVariant var = new PropVariant();
                var.vt = VT_BOOL;
                var.boolVal = enable;
                pPropStore.SetValue(ref propKey, ref var);
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(pPropStore);
            }
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Add that to your namespace and just call it when Form is Shown (winforms) or Window has loaded (WPF).

```
            IntPtr intPtr = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Your_app")[0].MainWindowHandle;
            EdgeGestureUtil.DisableEdgeGestures(intPtr, true);
```

And that's it - edge swipes will stop working for as long as application is running and windows is active. Once you close it - swipes will be working again.

Comment: Great and *complete* solution - appreciate that it is copy/paste ready.
I found it more convenient to use GetCurrentProcess() instead of GetProcessByName("...")[0].

Comment: Works perfect. I just used mainForm.Shown += delegate { } instead of GetProcessByName

Comment: I'm unable to make above code work on a touch screen, does it only work with tablet mode? @ClaytonBell

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [**PKEY_EdgeGesture_DisableTouchWhenFullscreen**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj553591(v=vs.85).aspx) function that was introduced with Windows 8.1.

I just created a small test and it appears to works on Windows 10 (build 10586) as well. Keep in mind that this only works for single-window solutions where the Window is running full screen. It works with both WPF and WinForms application. You need to pass a HWND of the window to the function.

You can find an example in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889683/how-do-i-turn-off-windows-8-1-gestures-and-setting-charm-bar-on-my-touch-screen).