# Disable screen edge gestures in Windows 10 UWP application

Tags: uwp, kiosk-mode

(Note: I have seen a couple [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34217231/how-to-programmatically-disable-edge-swipe-gesture-of-the-windows-10-tablet-scre) posted, but neither is specifically asking about Universal Windows Platform as I am.)

We are building a kiosk application for UWP/Win10 and have a bit of a unique requirement: we want the app to run in kiosk mode so that users cannot accidentally (or intentionally) switch out of the running app… *however*, the tricky part is that we also need to be able to, upon clicking a button, switch out of kiosk mode and launch another app.

It's my understanding that UWP apps *can* switch to other apps, but not if they are running in **assigned access**, which is the normal way that such apps can be locked down into kiosk mode.

So my question is is there any way to do both of these things (disable user app switching but allow programmatic app switching)? I have investigated disabling edge gestures as an alternative to assigned access and have found some lower level Win32 APIs that purportedly do this, but my research suggests there is no way to call these APIs from UWP.

Specifically I tried adding the [class defined in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38608549/238948), but it wouldn't compile. It looks like `MethodImplOptions` are completely different on UWP so the code from pinvoke.net doesn't work.

Another thought was that perhaps we can programmatically enable/disable assigned access on demand, but I'm guessing this is not possible given what I've read about assigned access.

(I just inherited this project and have almost no experience with this platform so any tips/pointers are greatly appreciated!)

Comment: Do you need your app to be eventually published to windows store? If not, you can try use [Brokered Windows Runtime Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to call the lower level Win32 APIs.

Comment: At this point no we don't. This looks very helpful, thanks!