# How to programmatically disable Three finger swap gesture

Tags: c#, desktop

Hey I have been trying to disable three finger swap gesture in my windows forms application. I found this article but its for disabling edge swap gestures: [How to programmatically disable edge swipe gesture of the windows 10 tablet screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34217231/how-to-programmatically-disable-edge-swipe-gesture-of-the-windows-10-tablet-scre)